# Botframework NodeJS - session.userData undefined when first opening chat

Tags: botframework

I want to greet the user with their name when they first open the page that contains the chatbot (I am using it as a web chat). So I need to have something like: Welcome back Joe.

I implemented this:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(message.address, 'WelcomeDialog');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and in WelcomeDialog, I have this:

```
bot.dialog('WelcomeDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.sendTyping();
        if (!session.userData.PreferredName) {
           //write logic to get user preferred name to call him/her with
           session.userData.PreferredName = "new name"
        }

        else if (!session.conversationData.loggedBefore) {
            session.send(`Welcome back ${session.userData.PreferredName}`)
            session.conversationData.loggedBefore = true;
        }

        session.endDialog()
    })
```

However, when I run this in webchat, session.userData is always empty even after filling it ONLY in the WelcomeDialog which was called from conversationUpdate.. However if I call another dialog and try to check session.userData, it will contain the values I added.. So basically, session.userData is always empty when I first open the bot, otherwise it works fine.

Also, it works fine in the emulator, just not in the webchat. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  This blog article describes a workaround: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/

Basically, it comes down to the fact that the Connector Services are what sends the **conversationUpdate** activity.  When **conversationUpdate** comes into the bot, it does not have the correct userId so the bot cannot construct the data bags.  If you send an event from the client after BotChat is initialized, that event will have the correct userId and everything will work as expected.  (The reason it works in the emulator is because the emulator does not use the connector services, but sends **conversationUpdate** itself.)

Comment: Thank you Eric. I didn't know about that. In my case, I am using the embedded code provided by the Web Channel of the bot, which is an iframe. In the article you sent me, they're using a client JavaScript.. how can I do the same?

Also, they're considering the webchat, what if I want to support Skype as well?

Comment: The iframed version simply does not support loading a dialog from 'conversationUpdate'.  And, Skype does not send 'conversationUpdate', you need to use 'contactRelationUpdate' for that channel.

Comment: Thanks Eric. So I need to write code to handle it for web chat and another code specifically for Skype?

Comment: Yes.  Channels behave differently.  MBF does the best it can to map everything to the shared Activity Schema, but not all channels participate the same way.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'll mark it as an answer. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes in case I have more concerns. Still new to this technology, so thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I posted another question, if you happen to know a way to work around it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904642/send-data-from-bot-to-client-in-directline-webchat-nodejs-botframework  .. thanks!

Comment: Hi Eric, can you please check this question if you have an idea about it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319992/botframework-map-is-not-a-function